# clion 19 error with load ROS 1 cmakelists, load cmakelist of A package,but output error about one unrelevant B package

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, clion

[image]

Let take  `/SLAM/vox_ws` as package A,
take `kimera_semantic_ws`  as  package  B,
they are all ROS projects.
If  I  use CLion to load `CMakeLists.txt` of the package A in `/home/lzw/resplendent_code/SLAM/vox_ws/src/voxgraph/voxgraph/CMakeLists.txt`

it will output the error at package B like

```
CMake Error at /home/lzw/resplendent_code/kimera_semantic_ws/devel/share/catkin_simple/cmake/catkin_simple-extras.cmake:38 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcblox.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "cblox", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "cblox" with any of
  the following names:

    cbloxConfig.cmake
    cblox-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cblox" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "cblox_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "cblox"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (catkin_simple)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/lzw/resplendent_code/SLAM/vox_ws/src/voxgraph/voxgraph/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/lzw/resplendent_code/SLAM/vox_ws/src/voxgraph/voxgraph/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I think it is very weird.

Comment: According to the error message, your code (`CMakeLists.txt`) somehow (probably, via `find_package`) includes the file `/home/lzw/resplendent_code/kimera_semantic_ws/devel/share/catkin_simple/cmake/catkin_simple-extras.cmake` and at line 7 calls the function `catkin_simple` which is defined in the included file. If you want to know the reason of this, then you need to **provide your code** (`CMakeLists.txt`). BTW, it is also a rule of Stack Overflow to provide the code in the question post. See [ask].

Comment: the  total  code  has  complicated  structure，could  i  send it  via email to you ？many  thanks

Comment: the total code has complicated structure，could i send it via email to you ？many thanks –

Comment: No, the *whole* code is not needed. You need to provide [mcve]: the simplified code which reproduces your problem, but doesn't include irrelevant details.